# Does Twitter Bootstrap conflict with progressive enhancement?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, semantic-markup, progressive-enhancement

I understand that the first step in progressive enhancement is to lay the information out in such a way that it makes sense on a simple device, e.g. one with no javascript or css capabilities.  In one particular case I have some information that is best suited to an unordered list, `<ul>`, so this is what I use.  Each data item is wrapped in an `<li>`.

When I consider the responsive aspects of my site, however, I would like the information laid out in three columns on medium and large devices.  Using Bootstrap this would mean wrapping a `<div class="col-md-4">` around each `<li>`, but this is not possible (since a `<div>` is not a valid child of a `<ul>`).

In view of this, I find myself considering `<p>` elements for each data item, rather than the `<li>`, and this would be a step backwards in terms of semantics.

Am I missing something, or is there a conflict here between Bootstrap and progressive enhancement?  Perhaps I should be using Bootstrap differently?  Or perhaps my understanding of progressive enhancement is not entirely accurate?

Comment: Voting to close as there isn't a specific programming issue being discussed here.

Comment: Graceful degradation is a popular alternative these days.

Comment: Every tool has a perspective, a point of view. When evaluating the available tools, you should consider whether the priorities of the tool align with your priorities (i.e. does it do what you want or are you going to have to fight it?). Now I can’t speak specifically to Bootstrap’s ability (or inability) to align with the philosophy of progressive enhancement, but I can say that it does make certain suppositions in the design of its components (like JS availability). Also, keep in mind that the original purpose of Bootstrap was to be able to whip up *prototypes* not to build production sites.

Comment: @MartinBean I would strongly disagree, just because the question doesn't have a specific coding issue doesn't mean it doesn't belong on this website.

Comment: @Dnwebdev You might want to take [Stack Overflow’s tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). From there: “Focus on questions about an **actual problem** you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.” Also: “Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are **primarily opinion-based**, or that are likely to **generate discussion** rather than answers.”

Comment: Fair enough, I am in the opinion of the web being more than just code. Conceptual questions seem to be shot down on SO as opposed to being discussed, I guess there needs to be a "UXoverflow" then. In the defense of the question, he is having a problem with progressively enhancing bootstrap which is a valid question. Edit - http://ux.stackexchange.com/   OP

Comment: @Dnwebdev I'm with you. MartinBean is wrong. HTML is a programming language and Progressive Enhancement is a particular design pattern. The poster clearly described what he has tried as a solution to make his unordered list work within the progressive enhancement design pattern and is asking for a specific solution. Perhaps the only error in the question is the title which is not specific enough.

Comment: Do you need your list to appear as a list (ie with bullets etc?) or is it sufficient to render the items as lines of content?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap isn't incompatible with progressive enhancement, although it does encourage you to use elements as structure rather than semantically.

Bootstrap doesn't provide facilities for every needed UX scenario. I'm not aware of any out-of-the-box provision for multi-column unordered lists. However, you can create your own extension to bootstrap using a technique such as: http://csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/